# Why this error is showing in line 7 as Runtime error

Tags: python, compiler-errors

```
def rectangle_area(x,y):
    z = x*y 
    print("The area is " + z)

rectangle_area('5','6')
```

```
Runtime error : on line 7
   rectangle_area('5','6')
```

Comment: The operator * is not defined for strings is it?

Comment: Please show your full traceback

Comment: Use numbers instead of text if you want to multiply.

Comment: You are using a string, use this insteead : rectangle_area(5,6)

Answer (score 1):

You're  trying to multiple two strings you should pass two integers for example `rectangle_area(5,6)`

```
def rectangle_area(x,y):
    z = x*y 
    print("The area is ", z)

rectangle_area(6,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to say that these are numbers and not some text

```
def rectangle_area(x,y):
    z = x*y 
    print("The area is " + str(z))

rectangle_area(int('5'),int('6'))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the description of binary operators in the documentation on Python 3.7

> The * (multiplication) operator yields the product of its arguments.
> **The arguments must either both be numbers, or one argument must be an integer and the other must be a sequence.** In the former case, the
> numbers are converted to a common type and then multiplied together.
> In the latter case, sequence repetition is performed; a negative
> repetition factor yields an empty sequence.

So this expression `x*y` is invalid when the both operands are not numbers.

You could call the function just like

```
rectangle_area( 5, 6)
```

Otherwise you need to convert the strings to numbers like

```
rectangle_area( int( '5' ), int( '6' ) )
```

Also it would be better to define the function the following way

```
def rectangle_area(x,y):
    return x * y
```

and in the caller of the function to write

```
print("The area is", rectangle( 5, 6 ) )
```

Pay attention to that you may not write

```
print("The area is " + z)
```

when z is a number. You should write

```
print("The area is", z)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you can't multiple strings

```
def rectangle_area(x,y):
    z = x * y
    print("The area is " + str(z))

rectangle_area(5, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

> in python we dont print text and vars like this `print("hello" + x)`
> we do it like this `print("hello", x)`

> next thing you have to remove this `''` from the function like so `rectangle_area(5,6)`

**I hope I've been helpful**